# Grails: Register job from external library

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-plugin, grails-services

I need to separate a grails service into a dedicated lilbrary in order to use this service across many applications. This works fine for the service itself as I am able to register the service bean in the `resources.groovy` (see https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/spring.html).

This service happens to use a quartz job to get some functionality triggered regularly. So naturally I would move this job into the library and need to register it in the main application.
How can that be achieved? Thanks for you time!

Comment: do you need to extract the functionality into a library or a grails plugin?

Comment: a library as I want to use the funcionality in grails applications with different grails versions.

Comment: then create a simple project with a few dependencies (on quartz) and integrate it to all other projects

Answer (score -1):

Create grails plugin using this guide:
https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/plugins.html

Then in src/main/groovy/YOUR_PACKAGE/YourPluginGrailsPlugin.groovy you can add bean configuration in doWithSpring() method (in same as resources.groovy way).